# How make an api call to google calendar in python without user input?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make a call to the google calendar api and retrieve events that i have planned. I followed the [[quickstart][1](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python)](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) to make an api call to google calander, while on my windows desktop it opens a web browser and asks my logged in google account for access, on my centos server it opens some sort of flow to get user info, however the text is all in german so i don't really understand whats happening, anyway i'm trying to make the api call to the google calendar without user input, i have acces to their client id and client secrets, is there any example or good guide that explains me how to do this? i have seen and understands how the oath 2,0 of google works but i just fail to see how i should put this in code. The example code is below.

```
from __future__ import print_function import datetime import pickle import os.path from googleapiclient.discovery import build from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle. SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'], end)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If ``user input`` you are saying is to input the code for authorization, how about using Service Account?

Comment: Using a service account would indeed help, but i can't find an example of using a service account, i'm trying to find an example that shows all code from authentication to authorization tokens. If you can show me some example of service accounts that would be great!

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you will use Service Account, can I ask you about your situation? 1. Can you create a Service Account? 2. Can you enable Calendar API? 3. Can you add the email to the calendar? By obtaining your response, I would like to prepare an answer.

Comment: My situation is i'm writing a small chatbot script for an small internet telephone company. I currently have have writen the script but i try to add employees their calendar so when callers want to make an appointment i can retrieve when they are free, suggest a date for appointment and than fill the date on their calendar. I currently have acces to a service account, and have the Calendar api 3 enabled. I'm not sure what you mean with the adding email to the calendar.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About adding email to the calendar, when Calendar API is used by the Service Account, the email of Service Account is required to be added to the calendar you want to access. So I asked it. About your situation, I cannot understand about ``i try to add employees their calendar``. You want to access to own calendar. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: i want to access their calendar so i can read their upcomming events, and write new events in it. I have read that its possible to "impersonate" users by using the credentials.with_subject() function.

Comment: If you want to access to other user's calendars using Service Account, each calendar is required to be shared with the Service Account. By the way, can I ask you about ``credentials.with_subject() function``?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount ( can't find the other webpage ) but this would set the user you would want to impersonate ( person who would do the action )

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize I couldn't resolve your issue.